# Can't put content over full page video background

Tags: html, video, background

Got the video background working but it either pushes down my content or covers everything. I've played around with z-index but it only seems to be working with text.

```
<video id="videobcg" preload="auto" autoplay loop muted="muted" volume="0">
<source src="_videos/college_de_boulogne.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="_videos/college_de_boulogne.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
</body>


#videobcg {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
z-index: 1;
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried -1 index for video element? (It would really help if you could show us more code).
It will never push down your content if it's position stays absolute.
As your last resort you can always use some JQuery plugins: http://www.sitepoint.com/background-video-plugins/, at least it will guarantee you an alright cross-browser support.